# Width of element is bigger when in browser is in windowed mode

Tags: html, css

Basically, I'm trying to make my first website, ever, and I'm having trouble already.

I'm making the navigation bar and it's all looking good, but as soon as I put my browser into windowed mode, the navigation bar extends beyond what it was, so I have to scroll sideways to reach the end of it.

P.S.
I'm new to stackoverflow, still trying to figure it out.
So I might do something I'm not supposed to, just let me know and I'll try to fix it.

Edit 1:
I'm using Google Chrome.

Here is the JSFiddle with full code:
http://goo.gl/Z5wvTn

If you look at the header and footer, you should be able to see that the main section and navigation bar is actually wider than them.
The navigation bar and main section are within a div, while the other elements arent.
This effect is on a much larger scale without JSFiddle.

Comment: Which browser are you using, and can you try with a different one?
I've created a JSFiddle, looks alright to me: http://jsfiddle.net/6y6Lk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create something like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6y6Lk/6/)

If yes, then use `%` or `em`in place of `pixels`

Comment: While your method works, its best practice to keep headers and footers within the wrapper div, then control the width of your wrapper div.

Comment: Well! Agree with you but it depends on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `header` and `footer` in the `wrapper div` and then `decrease or adjust` the `width` of the `.wrapper div in your css`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6y6Lk/5/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestive answer, but what I am trying to do is have the header and footer be all across the screen, not any less.

Comment: Change the width of your wrapper to `100%`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what @Aayushi Jain and @Shivam said use wrapper with percentage. That way, your wrapper will respond according to the window screen.

Look up responsive design if you want to know more about it.

My version would be to add width:100% on your wrapper instead of defining fixed width.

Also, practice on using ems and % like @Aayushi Jain said.

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: As my answer suggested :D